# How to make a tapered line in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way to make tapered lines in Sketch? I attached the way I do it in Illustrator as an example below.

[image: Tapered line in Illustrator]

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Sketch, but it does have a Vector Tool for making Bezier curves somewhat similar to the Pen Tool in Illustrator.

To make a tapering line in Illustrator without using a stroke style/profile it's easy enough to make by simply using the Pen Tool, so the same should be possible in Sketch and virtually any vector image editor with a similar tool.

Remember to set the stroke to none, and the fill to black.

Here's an example made in Illustrator
[image]
[image]

There's a tutorial on youtube showing how to use the Vector Tool in Sketch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=64&v=GWueR0dgt2A)

Comment: Exactly. You need to look at it as if it were a shape, not a line.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a tapered line in sketch is probably by creating an Oval with small height

[image: tapered line sketch].

If you want a "proper" tapered line or one that is not straight you are unfortunately left to do it yourself using the Vector Tool as has already been pointed out.